# 2nd place gets the bounty

Tags: discussion, answers, moderators, bounty, users

In Physics I asked a question and got 3 answers, 1 from a moderator and 2 from users. All 3 are good answers, but the moderator is spot on. I can tell 1 of the users are close in quality and took some thought. Since the moderator has 56k reputation and the user 300 would it be ok to award a bounty to a lesser answer while checking the moderator as the preferred answer?

Comment: I really don't think you should consider moderators any different from all the other users when using the main site. Moderators are users too, the just do *extra voluntary work* to help the site run smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, @DanielSank is right, moderator status doesn't mean _anything_ when we post answers or questions on the main site. This is still a reasonable thing to ask, for cases where you get one answer which is perfect and another one that is also very good, but I don't think there's any point in mentioning that one of the posters is a moderator. (It's possible your question would get a better reception if you edit that out.)

Comment: I can only guess you are referring to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227738/time-dilation-equals-red-shift-looking-in-or-blue-shift-looking-out), except the person has 28k, not 56k rep. Note that Rob Jeffries is *not* one of the [4 moderators](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Also, your fixation with behaving differently around moderators comes off as a bit cagey and unusual.

Comment: @Jen You asked if it is ok. Yes, it is totally ok. Do whatever you want with your own bounty.

Comment: Also @ChrisWhite I don't think Jen has a "fixation" with behaving differently around moderators. I know at least 2 Mods on other SE sites that _encourage_ the sharing of rep.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I don't act differently for moderators except if they ask that I change something I try to comply and not to upset them.

Comment: I think we've said this before, but on this site 'moderator' is reserved for [formal moderators](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), marked by a ♦ after their username. (This also denotes Stack Exchange staff like [Shog9](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2911/shog9) or [Sklivvz](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66/sklivvz).) There are plenty of other [high-reputation users](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), but referring to them as moderators only serves to make what you're saying less clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can award your bounty to whomever you like.

Comment: Well yah, but the user is asking for *advice*.

Comment: @DanielSank: They ask: *"Would it be ok..."* Yes. It would. It's their bounty, they can do with it as they please, I don't see what advice we could/should offer here.

Comment: In general, the answer is right, but there are some corner cases, e.g. you can't award a bounty to another one of your own accounts (if you have more than one). In case you consider that worth mentioning. ;-)

Comment: @Jen : Q&As on the SE network are supposed to be a repository of information for future readers, not just for the benefits&needs of OP. David Z's above comment should be viewed in this light. It is not aimed at any specific person in particular.